# Screen flickering after idle transition, inactivity closing computer, and startup

Tags: drivers, 20.04, suspend

As the title implies, whenever my computer(LG Gram, intel drivers, Ubuntu 20.04) enters standby mode the screen starts flashing and even though the mouse is responsive, the screen becomes unusable and i have to restart the computer to get it working again.

I've deduced the transition to idle mode has something to do with the problem and made it so the computer never enters it, but whenever I boot it up and leave it in the lockscreen for too long, connect an HDMI cable, or partially close the computer enough, the screen starts intensely flickering again and I have to turn it off. I have a dual boot with Windows, and it only seems to happen on Ubuntu, so that's why I'm asking this here.

Here is a video of the screen flickering:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/t9vny2/installed_ubuntu_and_standby_screen_flickers/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

[this is a log from before I rebooted, while the screen was flashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGXig.png)

Is the line that says "#AC: crashing the kernel on kernel split_logs" relevant?

Comment: It would be interesting to see what `dmesg -w` says. Open a terminal, start the command and go into lockscreen. Paste the newly written data from the output of the command into your question. BTW: You did not install any intel drivers but are using the default ones?

Comment: I tried, but the computer becomes unresponsive. Since I can't enter from the lockscreen once the screen starts flashing, I connected an HDMI cable to start the flickering(which worked), but I can't actually click on anything, so I couldn't copy the output. I also tried taking screenshots to see if i could read what the terminal says but they don't seem to save once I reboot the computer. Also, I use the default drivers.

Comment: check `journalctl -b 1` (==show me  the kernel logs from last boot) and check if you can see some error concerning your GPU - also check the /var/log/Xorg.log.1 file.  Which intel GPU do you have? If it is rather new, you might check if Ubuntu 22.04 will support it (just use a live usb stick)

Comment: I've updated my post to show the log. The computer is pretty new, so I might be able to use 22.04. Let me check.

Comment: Try it and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a fresh Xubuntu 22.04. The reason was that the after the installation the swap is only 2G in and I have 16G RAM which must be saved when hibernating. The following solved the issue:

```
sudo swapoff 
sudo fallocate -l 16G /swapfile
sudo swapon
```